# Problema de rotas com MVC 5 C#

Tags: c#, url, rotas

Já pesquisei, já passei 2 horas queimando a cachola porem não achei uma solução.
Será que alguém já teve esse problema?

Tenho o seguinte link:

**http://localhost:49609/Fabricante/EditarRegistro/53/1/4/G/3/13**

```
Controller -> Fabricante
Action -> EditarRegistro
Param01 ->53
Param02 ->1
Param03 ->4
...
Param05 -> 13.
```

Minha **rota** está configurada da seguinte maneira:

```
  ///ROTAS PARA FABRICANTE
            routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "EditarFabricante",
                    url: "{controller}/" +
                         "{action}/" +
                         "{org_tab_in_codigo}/" +
                         "{org_pad_in_Codigo}/" +
                         "{org_in_codigo}/" +
                         "{Org_Tau_In_Codigo}/" +
                         "{vFab_In_Codigo}/" +
                         "{Alf_In_codigo}",
                    defaults: new
                    {
                        controller = "Fabricante",
                        action = "EditarRegistro",
                        org_tab_in_codigo = UrlParameter.Optional,
                        org_pad_in_Codigo = UrlParameter.Optional,
                        org_in_codigo = UrlParameter.Optional,
                        Org_Tau_In_Codigo = UrlParameter.Optional,
                        vFab_In_Codigo = UrlParameter.Optional,
                        Alf_In_codigo = UrlParameter.Optional
                    });
```

Meu **controller** está configurado:

```
    [Route("EditarFabricante")]
    public ActionResult EditarRegistro(int Org_Tab_In_Codigo,
                                       int Org_Pad_In_Codigo,
                                       int Org_In_Codigo,
                                       string Org_Tau_In_Codigo,
                                       string vFab_In_Codigo,
                                       int Alf_In_Codigo)
    {
        ViewBag.NotView = ViewData.vNotView;
        var appFabricante = new WebEstFabricanteAplicacao();
        var webFabricante = appFabricante.ListarUmRegistrodaOrganizacao(Org_Tab_In_Codigo,
                                                                        Org_Pad_In_Codigo,
                                                                        Org_In_Codigo,
                                                                        Org_Tau_In_Codigo,
                                                                        int.Parse(vFab_In_Codigo.ToString()),
                                                                        Alf_In_Codigo);

        return View(webFabricante);
    }
```

[EDIT]

Meu **button** para editar o registro está da seguinte maneira:

```
                                                       <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("EditarFabricante", 
                                    new {action = "EditarRegistro",
                                    org_tab_in_codigo = item.Org_Tab_In_Codigo,
                                    org_pad_in_Codigo = item.Org_Pad_In_Codigo,
                                    org_in_codigo = item.Org_In_Codigo,
                                    Org_Tau_In_Codigo = item.Org_Tau_St_Codigo,
                                    vFab_In_Codigo = item.Fab_In_Codigo,
                                    Alf_In_codigo = item.Alf_In_Codigo})"
                               title="Editar Registro"
                               onclick="Loading();"
                               class="btn btn-primary">
                                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                            </a>
```

[/EDIT]

Ao clicar no **button** ele apresenta o erro:
[image: Erro]

Não consigo decifrar porque raios, o meu controller está pegando o valor do vFAB_IN_CODIGO como null, sendo que o mesmo está identificado na URL.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[EDIÇÃO]

Agora descobri que o problema ocorre na segunda ROTA criada, quando chamo a primeira ROTA personalizada o sistema executa normalmente, porem ao executar outra ROTA com os mesmos parâmetros o sistema apresenta o erro de parâmetro nulo.

```
        ///ROTAS PARA FABRICANTE
        routes.MapRoute(
                name: "EditarFabricante",
                url: "{controller}/" +
                     "{action}/" +
                     "{org_tab_in_codigo}/" +
                     "{org_pad_in_Codigo}/" +
                     "{org_in_codigo}/" +
                     "{Org_Tau_In_Codigo}/" +
                     "{vFab_In_Codigo}/" +
                     "{Alf_In_codigo}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Fabricante",
                    action = "EditarRegistro",
                    org_tab_in_codigo = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    org_pad_in_Codigo = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    org_in_codigo = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    Org_Tau_In_Codigo = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    vFab_In_Codigo = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    Alf_In_codigo = UrlParameter.Optional
                });


        routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ExcluirFabricante",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{org_tab_in_codigo}/{org_pad_in_Codigo}/{org_in_codigo}/{Org_Tau_In_Codigo}/{vFab_In_Codigo}/{Alf_In_codigo}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Fabricante",
                    action = "ExcluirRegistro",
                    org_tab_in_codigo = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    org_pad_in_Codigo = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    org_in_codigo = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    Org_Tau_In_Codigo = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    vFab_In_Codigo = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    Alf_In_codigo = UrlParameter.Optional
                });
```

Executando a primeira rota:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar chama normalmente para a ROTA de edição.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora ao clicar em excluir que chama a segunda rota com os mesmos parâmetros, porem Action diferente da erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou fazendo errado?

[/EDIÇÃO]

Comment: Tentou invés de receber `string vFab_In_Codigo` receber `int vFab_In_Codigo`. Na mensagem de erro diz que não está vindo inteiro, talvez, por algum motivo(sobrenatural) não esteja convertendo int para string

Comment: Na verdade ele é **int** coloquei como string para verificar o valor que estava retornando, mas sempre retorna como null. [link]https://imgur.com/a/g34oyD6

Comment: `vFab_In_Codigo` é `int` ou `int?` ???

Comment: "int", como é um botão de edição de registro ele tem que passar as chaves / compostas para achar esse registro no banco.

Comment: e você reparou que na view você atribui `item.Org_Tau_St_Codigo` para `Org_Tau_In_Codigo`, está certa essa diferença no nome? Eu construi a sua estrutura aqui e não obtive nenhum erro.

Comment: Leandro, verifiquei que o problema ocorre na segunda rota em diante. Editei o post com alguns detalhes novos que detectei.

Comment: As duas rotas têm o mesmo número de parâmetros; como você acha que o MVC vai conseguir resolver qual é qual?

Comment: Marcelo pensando no que você disse, cheguei a outra conclusão/solução. Vou postar o {GATO} que foi feito para funcionar isso.

Answer (score 0):

Cheguei a essa solução, não tenho certeza se é o correto pooooorem....

Modifiquei as duas **ROTAS**:

```
        ///ROTAS PARA FABRICANTE
        routes.MapRoute(
                name: "EditarFabricante",
                url: "{controller}/" +
                     "{action}/" +
                     "{org_tab_in_codigo}/" +
                     "{org_pad_in_Codigo}/" +
                     "{org_in_codigo}/" +
                     "{org_tau_in_codigo}/" +
                     "{fab_in_codigo}/" +
                     "{alf_in_codigo}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Fabricante",
                    action = "EditarRegistro"
                });


        routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ExcluirFabricante",
                url: "{controller}/" +
                     "{action}/" +
                     "{org_tab_in_codigo}/" +
                     "{org_pad_in_Codigo}/" +
                     "{org_in_codigo}/" +
                     "{org_tau_in_codigo}/" +
                     "{fab_in_codigo}/" +
                     "{alf_in_codigo}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Fabricante",
                    action = "ExcluirRegistro"
                });
```

Antes eu estava passando os parâmetros diretamente na **ROTA**, tirei os parâmetros mantendo a URL normalmente. Agora eu faço a modificação de rota diretamente no **controller**.

**[Route("Fabricante/EditarRegistro/{org_tab_in_codigo}/{org_pad_in_Codigo}/{org_in_codigo}/{org_tau_in_codigo}/{fab_in_codigo}/{alf_in_codigo}")]**

```
    [Route("Fabricante/EditarRegistro/{org_tab_in_codigo}/{org_pad_in_Codigo}/{org_in_codigo}/{org_tau_in_codigo}/{fab_in_codigo}/{alf_in_codigo}")]
public ActionResult EditarRegistro(int org_tab_in_codigo,
                                           int org_pad_in_Codigo,
                                           int org_in_codigo,
                                           string org_tau_in_codigo,
                                           int fab_in_codigo,
                                           int alf_in_codigo)
        {
            ViewBag.NotView = ViewData.vNotView;
            var appFabricante = new WebEstFabricanteAplicacao();
            var webFabricante = appFabricante.ListarUmRegistrodaOrganizacao(org_tab_in_codigo,
                                                                            org_pad_in_Codigo,
                                                                            org_in_codigo,
                                                                            org_tau_in_codigo,
                                                                            fab_in_codigo,
                                                                            alf_in_codigo);

            return View(webFabricante);
        }
```

Assim ele aceitou as **ROTAS** :

http://localhost:49609/Fabricante/EditarRegistro/53/1/4/G/3/13

http://localhost:49609/Fabricante/ExcluirRegistro/53/1/4/G/3/13

E não se perdendo e passando valor nulo para parâmetro inteiro.

Obrigado a todos.